# Ruby on Rails api and client app. How to get data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

i have an ruby on rails api app that returns an data on json format. I also have a ruby on rails client app that needs to get that data. how do i get it, so i can display it on view in the client app?

i can access the api app data in the browser. But im having a hard time getting the client app to be able to get that json data. For example: The api controllers is academic_titles_controllers, the method is  active_academic_titles, now this method renders a json view. im not able to access from the client app this view. however if the method is index i can do that.

In the Client app, the AcademicTitle model inheris from a class called UapApi

```
class UapApi < ActiveResource::Base
  MODE = 'dev' # api or dev

  self.site = 'http://localhost:3003/'
  self.format = :json
end
```

Comment: Post the URL you use in the browser.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/active_academic_titles?academic_unit_id=9 This is the json view url. the method name is just active_academic_titles and the json view has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

With open-uri

```
url = "http://..."
data = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
```

Or using 'net'

```
require "net/http"

url = "http://..."
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
data = JSON.parse(resp.body)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23319532/1373197).

Comment: its not the connection, with the index method in any api controller i have no problem getting the data to the client. the problem is with other methods that dont have a name that comes by default on rails

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) gem:

```
conn = Faraday.new
response = conn.get do |req|
  req.url("localhost:3000/active_academic_titles")
  req.params['academic_unit_id'] = 9
end
data = JSON.parse(response.body)
```